# The 'find' command gives an error even though I am redirecting standard error to /dev/null

Tags: bash, find

My find command is generating errors that I do not want to see. I am redirecting stderr to /dev/null but it's not working. How can I hide it?

```
~$ find . -type f -name '*.js' -print | xargs grep self.setNetwork 2>/dev/null
find: ‘./_statCon’: Permission denied
./oz-workspace/src/js/truffle-contract.js:            self.setNetwork(network_id);
./oz-workspace/src/js/truffle-contract.js:                self.setNetwork(uris[i]);
./oz-workspace/src/js/truffle-contract.js:            self.setNetwork(network_id);
```

Comment: Redirections are applied to simple commands, not pipelines. You are only redirecting `xarg`'s standard error, not `find`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And it's gone:

```
( find . -type f -name '*.js' -print 2>/dev/null ) | xargs grep self.setNetwork 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: No need to run find in subshell for that.

Answer (score 5):

The error's coming from `find`, not `grep`.

```
find . -type f -name '*.js' -print 2>/dev/null | xargs grep self.setNetwork
```

For what it's worth, you should use `-print0 | xargs -0` to handle file names with whitespace correctly.

```
find . -type f -name '*.js' -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 grep self.setNetwork
```

Or better yet, use `-exec`.

```
find . -type f -name '*.js' -exec grep self.setNetwork {} + 2>/dev/null
```